# Type error when testing both boolean and number in ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-aot

If I have a template like this (`readOnly` is a boolean and `arrayOfStuff` is an array):

```
<span *ngIf="!readOnly && arrayOfStuff && arrayOfStuff.length">Hey</span>
```

`ng build --prod` or`ng serve --prod` both give the error:

```
ERROR in /Development/project/src/$$_gendir/app/components/thing/thing.component.ngfactory.ts (767,11): Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

...but if I remove the boolean check it works fine:

```
<span *ngIf="arrayOfStuff && arrayOfStuff.length">Hey</span>
```

...or if I make the length check specifically a numeric comparison it works fine:

```
<span *ngIf="!readOnly && arrayOfStuff && (arrayOfStuff.length >0)">Hey</span>
```

Why is it OK to do a falsy check against `arrayOfStuff.length` when I'm checking if an object exists, but it is not OK to do this when I'm checking the value of a boolean along with it?

Again, this only happens when I am actually generating a production build with `ng build --prod` or `ng serve --prod`.  It is not a problem for development.

To be clear - I can make the problem go away, but I want to understand why it is OK to check `arrayOfStuff.length` directly in one case, and not in the other.

Angular v4, @angular/cli v1.0.1.

Comment: this is a typical behavior and happens because of AOT. Angular cli uses AOT by default when you use `--prod`

Comment: I guessed that, but what are the specific rules that must be followed?  Why does AOT allow a comparison that includes a number and checking if an object exists, but doesn't allow you to compare those two along with a boolean?

Comment: the AOT compiler analyzes the html statically. And it is looking for a very specific type, in the case of `ngIf` its a boolean. When you use `JIT` javascript runtime (browser) will convert objects to boolean via truthy/falsy mechanism.

Comment: Right - but in one of the examples that works correctly, none of the types are a boolean and it still works.  Why does it accept it in this case but not in the case when a boolean IS one of the types?  Specifically this works, but should not based on your explanation: `<span *ngIf="arrayOfStuff && arrayOfStuff.length">Hey</span>`

Answer (score 1):

When you do not use comperators javascript tries to use type-coercion on variables. Since it tries it in here and cannot change it directly to boolean it gives you error. However when you make it

```
array.length > 0
```

it does not try that because all variables are boolean. Apperantly problem is that primitive number cannot be changed to boolean. You can use

```
!!array.length
```

to get your desired result

Comment: That doesn't explain why `<span *ngIf="arrayOfStuff && arrayOfStuff.length">Hey</span>` works correctly and only stops working once a boolean is added to the mix.  I'm trying to determine the rules that govern this - I had already obtained a workaround using the first method you suggest.